# AngularJS : directive ng-transclude to input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

Im trying create a directive which add ng-transclude value to input field value attribute in html template:

**directive** I've created:

```
module.directive('editInput', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '<p ng-show="value == false" ng-transclude></p>' +
        '<input ng-show="value == true" placeholder="" value="" ng-transclude/>'
    }
});
```

looking for something which adds **ng-transclude** value to value attribute in input element

template:

```
<edit-input value="isEditModeActive">{{person.name}}</edit-input>
```

currently I get this html output:

```
<input ng-show="value == true" placeholder="" value="" ng-transclude="" class="">
<span class="ng-binding">Name</span></input>
```

but really I need this html output:

```
<input ng-show="value == true" placeholder="" value="Name">
```

Comment: have you tried entering the expression as a string? eg: `ng-show="'value == true'"` (note single quotes inside double quotes)

Comment: No, ng-show is not in connection with the issue. I mean the issue is in directive editInput where ng-transclude is passed in wrong way for displaying it in value attribute on input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script.js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.person = {};
  $scope.person.name = 'Rahul';
})
.directive('editInput', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '=',
            editName: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: 
        '<p ng-show="value == false" ng-transclude></p>' +
        '<input ng-show="value == true" placeholder="" value="{{editName}}" />'
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <script src= "angular.js"></script>

    <script src= "script.js"></script>

    <edit-input value="true" edit-name="{{person.name}}">{{person.name}}</edit-input>
    {{person.name}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

I get the expression {{member.firstname}} instead of Name in value attribute on input element:

That means I get this html output:
<input ng-show="value == true" placeholder="" value=„{{person.name}“ class="">

But I need something like this html output:
<input ng-show="value == true" placeholder="" value=„Name“ class="">

Tomorrow I’ll try to find a working solution.

Comment: How about the updated code? I've removed the compile function and introduced a new attribute edit-name in the html. I read that attribute in the directive's isolate scope and use that in the template.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for. With new attribute edit-name it's possible to solve my problem. Thanks a lot for your support!